# How do I hide a column in React-Table (initialState)?

Tags: reactjs, hide, show-hide, react-table

Now that I have a React-Table working, I would like to hide some columns.
Seems like this has something to do with initialState, but I can not get the correct syntax.

Here is my code.  Where and how do I add in the initialState code.  Looking to hide the column header: 'userId'
Code compiles and runs, but the userId column still displays.

I have included the TableContainer code as I know beleive this is all related.
...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Container, Card, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, } from 'reactstrap';
import TableContainer from '../Services/TableContainer';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import UserService from '../Services/UserService'
//import { SelectColumnFilter } from './../Services/filters';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const doFetch = async () => { const res = await UserService.getUsers(); 
      setData(res.data) };
    doFetch();
  }, []);


    const editUser = (row) =>{
    this.props.history.push(`/add-user/${row}`);
    }

    const renderRowSubComponent = (row) => {
    const {
      //usersId,
      usersfirstName,
      userslastName,
      usersaccessLevel,
      usersphoneNumber,
    } = row.original;
    return (
      <Card style={{ width: '18rem', margin: '0 auto' }}>
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle>
            <strong>{`${userslastName}, ${usersfirstName}`} </strong>
          </CardTitle>
          <CardText>
            <strong>Access Level</strong>: {`${usersaccessLevel}`} <br />
            <strong>Phone Number</strong>: {`${usersphoneNumber}`} <br />
          </CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    );
  };


  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: () => null,
        id: 'expander', // 'id' is required
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <span {...row.getToggleRowExpandedProps()}>
            {row.isExpanded ? '' : ''}
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        Header: 'usersId',
        accessor: 'usersId',
        disableSortBy: true,
        disableFilters: true,
      },
      {
        Header: 'Last Name',
        accessor: 'userslastName',
      },
      {
        Header: 'First Name',
        accessor: 'usersfirstName',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'usersemailAddress',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Signon Name',
        accessor: 'userssignonName',
      },
      {
        Header: '',
        id: 'click-edit',
        Cell: ({ row }) => (<button>Delete</button>)
      },
      {
        Header: '',
        id: 'click-delete',
        Cell: ({ row }) => (<button onClick={(e) => editUser.bind(row)}>Edit</button>)
      },
      ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <Container style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
      <TableContainer
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        hiddenColummns={['usersId']}
        renderRowSubComponent={renderRowSubComponent}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;

import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  useTable,
  useSortBy,
  useFilters,
  useExpanded,
  usePagination,
} from 'react-table';
// import { Table, Row, Col, Button, Input, CustomInput } from 'reactstrap';
import { Table, Row, Col, Button, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { Filter, DefaultColumnFilter } from './filters';

const TableContainer = ({ columns, data, renderRowSubComponent }) => {
  const initialState = { hiddenColumns: ['usersId'] };
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    prepareRow,
    visibleColumns,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn: { Filter: DefaultColumnFilter },
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10, initialState},
    },
    useFilters,
    useSortBy,
    useExpanded,
    usePagination
  );

  const generateSortingIndicator = (column) => {
    return column.isSorted ? (column.isSortedDesc ? ' ' : ' ') : '';
  };

  const onChangeInSelect = (event) => {
    setPageSize(Number(event.target.value));
  };

  const onChangeInInput = (event) => {
    const page = event.target.value ? Number(event.target.value) - 1 : 0;
    gotoPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Table bordered hover {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                  <div {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                    {column.render('Header')}
                    {generateSortingIndicator(column)}
                  </div>
                  <Filter column={column} />
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>

        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <Fragment key={row.getRowProps().key}>
                <tr>
                  {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                    return (
                      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
                {row.isExpanded && (
                  <tr>
                    <td colSpan={visibleColumns.length}>
                      {renderRowSubComponent(row)}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                )}
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>

      <Row style={{ maxWidth: 1000, margin: '0 auto', textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Col md={3}>
          <Button
            color='primary'
            onClick={() => gotoPage(0)}
            disabled={!canPreviousPage}
          >
            {'<<'}
          </Button>
          <Button
            color='primary'
            onClick={previousPage}
            disabled={!canPreviousPage}
          >
            {'<'}
          </Button>
        </Col>
        <Col md={2} style={{ marginTop: 7 }}>
          Page{' '}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>
        </Col>
        <Col md={2}>
          <Input
            type='number'
            min={1}
            style={{ width: 70 }}
            max={pageOptions.length}
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={onChangeInInput}
          />
        </Col>
        <Col md={2}>
          {/* <CustomInput */}
          <Input
          type='select'
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={onChangeInSelect}
          >
            {'>'}
            {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map((pageSize) => (
              <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                Show {pageSize}
              </option>
            ))}
          {/* </CustomInput> */}
          </Input>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <Button color='primary' onClick={nextPage} disabled={!canNextPage}>
            {'>'}
          </Button>
          <Button
            color='primary'
            onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)}
            disabled={!canNextPage}
          >
            {'>>'}
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default TableContainer;
```

...

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

For React Table V8, the columns can be hidden by setting the `columnVisibility` in the initial state:

```
const table = useReactTable({
    ...
    initialState: {
      columnVisibility: { <column_accessor>: false },
    },
    ...
});
```

[React Table - Column Visibility](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/column-visibility)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The docs are kinda of bad and difficult to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using react-table v8 or higher the 'show : false' IS NOT gonna work in:

```
    {
        Header: 'usersId',
        accessor: 'usersId',
        show: false
    },
```

Many places that I looked at told to use
'const initialState = { hiddenColumns: ['userId'] };'
inside the useTable Object. BUT for me, the ONLY WAY IT WORKED was with 'columnVisibility: { your_accesor_key: false },'
inside the state Object like this:

```
const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
        columnVisibility: { _id: false },
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting show prop to false in the Column header you want hidden, like this:

```
{
    Header: 'usersId',
    accessor: 'usersId',
    disableSortBy: true,
    disableFilters: true,
    show: false
}
```

Comment: I have added this property it doesn't work. Here u can get the link of the demo -https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-sorting-9dp6o0?file=/src/main.tsx:578-582

Comment: Oh I see you're using v8 of ReactTable, that's why it didn't work. For version 8 you must use initialState like this:  

const initialState = { hiddenColumns: ['userId'] };  //add any columns you want to hide in this array.
then add initialState in the useTable object.